# Communicate with Alexa Skill through API

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Is there a way to connect to integrate Alexa in my own system (RaspberryPi / Respeaker)? 
I would like to be able to trigger skills through a Raspberry Pi.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should explore [Alexa Voice Services](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-voice-service)

> The Alexa Voice Service enables you to access cloud-based Alexa
>   capabilities with the support of AVS APIs, hardware kits, software
>   tools, and documentation. We simplify building voice-forward devices
>   with Alexa built-in by handling complex speech recognition and natural
>   language understanding in the cloud, reducing your development costs
>   and accelerating your time to market. Best of all, regular Alexa
>   updates bring new features to your device and add support for a
>   growing assortment of compatible smart home devices. Build with AVS,
>   and become part of the Alexa family.

Here is the github link for code integration exploarion

https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk